# Close icon doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have a close icon that works great in the Chrome Browser. However, it doesn't work or "close" in Mozilla browser. I tried different things, but I was unable to fix it. What is not working in Mozilla and How do I fix it?

```html
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true" ng-click="c.resetModalFlow()">&times;</span>    
</button>
```

Comment: This looks like angular. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If you using twitter bootstrap you need to define a data-dismiss like this

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the span and put everything in my button tag. It is working fine now.

```html
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="c.resetModalFlow()">&times;</button>
```